# Determine date/time of original post

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to determine the original date/time of a Wordpress blog post?

Take for example [this blog post](http://imaginationdesigns.wordpress.com/cutting-edge-building-products-technology/).  There is no way to determine the date/time of the original posting.  However if you leave a comment then the date/time it was left is published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a blog "post", but a [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages). It doesn't share the date it was posted because it's meant to act as a web page that can change over time, not a post with information that may correlate to a single point in time.

Comment: While I agree with your general statement, the date/time can most definitely be shown on a WP page/post should one desire.

Comment: Ok - thanks for pointing out the difference between "post" and "Page".  When I see "Wordpress" pages I immediately think it is a blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to show the date/time on a page, this is absolutely possible. You can use the following code to display it. Just paste this code in the loop that is used in the page.php file of your theme

```
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
```

In order to style the date as you wish, see this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

Comment: I am not the programmer.  But simply someone that came by the page.